# "Doomed to fail" Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I was building a rail road, in minecraft, on the xbox 360, in the over world, wearing all diamond armour at night. A spider attacked. I thought no big deal, hit it with my ax. Instead the screen got jumpy, and I died almost instantly. 
The message on the screen read "[player] Doomed to fail." when I respawned. Then I went back and all my stuff was gone.  This is an unmoded version of the game, what happened?

Comment: I think you mean “doomed to fall”

Answer (score 1):

"was doomed to fall" is only a variant on "hit the ground too hard". The only explanation for your stuff disappearing was that you took too long to get back to your stuff. I'm not sure about bugs in the game as I don't own a copy of the Xbox version.